# iOS Memory Management - Issue with growing ImageIO_PNG_Data and CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, allocation

I'm having issues with an application where the memory continues to grow each time a push to a specific view.  The process followed to recreate this increase in memory is:

1. Show User Login View Controller
2. Push Home View Controller
3. Push Settings View Controller
4. Log User Out (A button in the settings view controller) - Pops to User Login View Controller
5. Login and Push Home View Controller

Every time I push to the Home View Controller (even though I have confirmed that the previous one is being deallocated) the memory jumps up 6+ mb's.  I profiled the app and saw one glaring issue with the VM:ImageIO_PNG_Data and VM:CoreAnimation categories in Allocations.

[image]

Some of these are occurring in a class I am using called Masking View which draws a specified portion of a layer below that view.  The code used to draw is listed below:

```
//Draw project image
CGRect newRect = self.frame;
if (useCustomFrame){
    newRect = customFrame;
}

CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.projectedImage CGImage], newRect);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image);

// Release Context
CGImageRelease(image);
```

Comment: Try releasing the context. CGContextRelease(context);

Comment: Releasing the context leads to an error, I think due to overreleasing since this is ARC: CGContextResetState: invalid context 0x9296780. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: You want to run it with the Leaks instrument, not Allocations. The biggest thing leaked also tends not to be the thing responsible for the leak.

Comment: I had profiled it with Leaks previously hoping to find something, but am returning 0 leaked objects.  Thats probably the biggest thing throwing me off.

Comment: The problem may not be a leak but just abandoned memory. That means that you still have valid references to the image from somewhere, but it's not accessible anymore. Try doing some generational analysis (aka heap shot analysis) on your home view controller - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html

Answer (score 2):

Growing memory issue most of the time come cause of 2 ways:

1.Check you image resolution which you are using in you code, use required image resolution only.

Suppose you are using 40x40 image size for 1X, 80x80 in 2x so on..
Then use only required resolution not more then that.

2. Check you are using updated Lazy loading library.

Use Memory Allocation tool and check VM allocation, if you got any IMAGEIO regarding issue then defiantly you have contained high resolution image in you NSMainBundle.

Resize high resolution image in required resolution and use imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageName.